# UI Test Automation for native (linux) based application (not web or desktop)

Tags: automation, gui, embedded-systems

We have a controller with the UI. We need to automate the UI testing for the same. 
The challenge is, the application is not Web browser/Desktop based - but it is a linux based target device.

The UI development is carried out using STORYBOARD engine by CRANK software.
We need to perform following:

1) Capture the current screen of the target UI
2) Trigger an event/action
3) Again capture the current screen of the target UI
4) Compare 1) & 2) and process the results

There are many tools available in market for web/desktop based applications, however, we are not able to find any tool/solution for native based application.

TIA!
Dhwani Vaishnav

Comment: I think this is going to depend on your desktop ... gnome/kde/etc? Or maybe there is something for qt ...